# How can I Change dimnames of matrices and data frames in R

Tags: r, dimensions, r-rownames, r-colnames

Let's say I have created the following matrix:

```
> x <- matrix(1:20000,nrow=100)
> x[1:10,1:10]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1  101  201  301  401  501  601  701  801   901
 [2,]    2  102  202  302  402  502  602  702  802   902
 [3,]    3  103  203  303  403  503  603  703  803   903
 [4,]    4  104  204  304  404  504  604  704  804   904
 [5,]    5  105  205  305  405  505  605  705  805   905
 [6,]    6  106  206  306  406  506  606  706  806   906
 [7,]    7  107  207  307  407  507  607  707  807   907
 [8,]    8  108  208  308  408  508  608  708  808   908
 [9,]    9  109  209  309  409  509  609  709  809   909
[10,]   10  110  210  310  410  510  610  710  810   910
```

What are the methods in R to change row and column names? For example, I like row names to be `SS1, SS2, ..., SS100` and column names to be `M1, M2, ..., M200`. I usually work with data with 1000s of rows and columns, and I need a good method to do that. Some people use something like `attributes(x)$dimnames <- list(...)` and some use `rownames <- paste(...)`. What are all possible methods?

My second question is, can I use the same methods after I convert the matrix to a data frame?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From comment to answer:

```
row.names(x) <- paste("SS", 1:nrow(x), sep="")
colnames(x) <-  paste("M" , 1:ncol(x), sep="")
```

As @doug wrote, it works for matrices and data frames.

Answer (score 7):

Yes same methods will work (matrix/data.frame)--see below:

```
A = matrix(1:12, nrow=4)
colnames(A) = c("col1", "col2", "col3")
row.names(A) = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4")

dfA = as.data.frame(A)
row.names(dfA) = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4")
colnames(A) = c("C1", "C2", "C3")
```

And to save time, you can do this:

```
x = rep("col", dim(M)[2])
y = 1:dim(M)[2]
colnames(M) = paste(x, y, sep="")
```

Comment: OK but I have 1000s of rows&columns. I just can't type r1, r2, ... r1253, ... etc. There should be some automatic counter and pasting operations.

Comment: `row.names(A) <- paste("SS",1:nrow(A),sep="");colnames(A)<-paste("M",1:ncol(A),sep="")`

Comment: @Marek: Could you please add this as an answer?

Comment: edited my answer to include a snippet to automate row and col names creation

Comment: At the same time :) BTW you don't need to `rep` prefix ("col"), `paste` do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is within a list you can do.

```
 dimnames(x)[[1]]<-paste("SS", 1:nrow(x), sep="")
 dimnames(x)[[2]]<-paste("M" , 1:ncol(x), sep="")
```

Comment: sorry not very good with matrices, can you give an example of when the dimnames(matrix) will be a list?

Comment: It isn't that the dimnames are a list, is that the matrix is within a list. If the matrix is within a list you cannot use the row.names and colnames attributes. Also dimnames could be used for arrays of order greater than 2.

Comment: matrix_in_a_list = list(matrix(1:4,2,2,dimnames=list(c("a","b"),1:2))) ; dimnames(matrix_in_a_list) gives me NULL.. what happened?

Comment: matrix_in_a_list = list(matrix(1:4,2,2)) ;

dimnames(matrix_in_a_list[[1]])<-list(c("a","b"),1:2)

Comment: You have to assign the dimnames to the matrix within the list not to the list itself. Also dimname is an attribute which needs to be directly referenced.